# Como mostrar datasets correctamente en una gráfica de barras apiladas usando Chart.js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, chart.js

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño dashboard en `ASP.NET`, con la ayuda de `C#` y estoy presentando un problema al generar una gráfica de barras horizontales apiladas (stacked horizontal bar) usando [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html).

Tengo los datos de unos técnicos a los cuales se les asignaron cierta cantidad de tickets, que según la imagen corresponden al eje `Y` de la gráfica. `A`, `B`, `C` y `D` representan a cada técnico y los *datasets* del 1 al 4 representan el estado en el que se encuentra cada ticket. Lo que quiero obtener en la gráfica es la cantidad de tickets que tiene cada técnico teniendo en cuenta su estado. Adjunto una imagen de ejemplo de lo que quiero realizar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Error:**

Estoy realizando la gráfica de barras horizontal esperada tal como lo indico en el ejemplo anterior pero no he logrado que se vean los *datasets* y sus colores correctamente.

Lo que he logrado hasta ahora es ver los técnicos con la cantidad de tickets que tiene cada uno, pero el *dataset* que representa el estado en la parte inferior de la gráfica se repite, ademas de `ASIGNADO` tengo otros estados y cada *dataset*, o sea, cada estado, tiene que ir representado por un color:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ser mas exactos aquí agrego [el ejemplo de `Stacked bar` que se encuentra en la documentación de `Chart.js`](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/stacked.html)

Los datos se estructuran de la siguiente manera en la tabla desde donde estoy sacando la información que quiero mostrar, donde, `TK_HD_TICKETS_ID` son los tickets que están registrados y de donde quiero sacar la cantidad, en `TK_CT_STATUS_ID` se almacena el estado del ticket y en `TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID` es el técnico que tiene ese ticket

La siguiente es la función `Javascript` con la que voy cargar los datos en la gráfica:

```
function loadEmployeesChart() {
    document.getElementById("chart-employee").remove();
    let auxCanvasEmployee = document.createElement('canvas');
    auxCanvasEmployee.setAttribute('id', 'chart-employee');
    auxCanvasEmployee.setAttribute('style', 'width: 720px; height: 600px');

    document
        .querySelector('#chartEmployeeContainer')
        .appendChild(auxCanvasEmployee);

    var canvas = document.getElementById("chart-employee");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var dataEmployee;
    var myNewChart;

    $.ajax({
        url: document.getElementById("employeeChart").value,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            refreshType: document.getElementById("dataOption").value
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var dataChart = [];
            var label = [];
            var datalabels = [];
            var stacks = []

            for (let idx in data.DashboardTicketList) {
                if (data.DashboardTicketList.hasOwnProperty(idx)) {
                    dataChart.push(data.DashboardTicketList[idx].TicketsCount);
                    label.push(data.DashboardTicketList[idx].TicketsAsignedTo);
                    datalabels.push(data.DashboardTicketList[idx].TicketsClasificationType);                
                }
            }

            var count = false;
            for (let idx in dataChart) {
                if (dataChart[idx] > 0) {
                    count = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (count) {
                document.getElementById('noDataEmployee').style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('noDataEmployee').style.display = 'block';
            }

            dataEmployee = { 
                labels: label,
                datasets: [{
                    label: datalabels,
                    data: dataChart,
                }],    
            };

            myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'horizontalBar',           
                data: dataEmployee,
                options: {
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{                            
                            stacked: true // this should be set to make the bars stacked
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            stacked: true // this also..
                        }]
                    },
                    legend: {
                        position: 'bottom',
                        padding: 5,
                        labels:
                        {
                            pointStyle: 'circle',
                            usePointStyle: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                
            });
        },
        error: function () { }
    });   
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema que tienes está en la transformación que haces de los datos que te llegan de la consulta y en la implementación de los mismos. Prácticamente estás creando tantos `labels` o `datasets` como resultados obtienes de la consulta, y esto deberías hacerlo agrupando los resultados, de lo contrario tendrás muchos datos repetidos. Lo mejor es que tus datos ya vinieran agrupados del servidor, pero tomando como fuente los datos que te llegan en este momento, intentaré describirte paso por paso una posible solución (aunque hay muchas posibles).

Imagina que la consulta te devuelve un número `x` de filas, tomemos para este ejemplo las siguientes:

```
[
    {TicketsCount: 44, TicketsAsignedTo: "A", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 1"},
    {TicketsCount: 55, TicketsAsignedTo: "B", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 1"},
    {TicketsCount: 41, TicketsAsignedTo: "C", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 1"},
    {TicketsCount: 37, TicketsAsignedTo: "D", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 1"},
    {TicketsCount: 53, TicketsAsignedTo: "A", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 2"},
    {TicketsCount: 32, TicketsAsignedTo: "B", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 2"},
    {TicketsCount: 33, TicketsAsignedTo: "C", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 2"},
    {TicketsCount: 52, TicketsAsignedTo: "D", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 2"},
    {TicketsCount: 12, TicketsAsignedTo: "A", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 3"},
    {TicketsCount: 17, TicketsAsignedTo: "B", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 3"},
    {TicketsCount: 11, TicketsAsignedTo: "C", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 3"},
    {TicketsCount: 9,  TicketsAsignedTo: "D", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 3"},
    {TicketsCount: 9,  TicketsAsignedTo: "A", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 4"},
    {TicketsCount: 7,  TicketsAsignedTo: "B", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 4"},
    {TicketsCount: 5,  TicketsAsignedTo: "C", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 4"},
    {TicketsCount: 8,  TicketsAsignedTo: "D", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 4"},
    {TicketsCount: 40, TicketsAsignedTo: "E", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 1"}
]
```

Primero que todo, se deben crear los `labels` que necesita el gráfico (estos deben ser únicos, no debe haber elementos repetidos):

```
const labels = Object.keys(
    consulta.reduce((obj, label) => (obj[label.TicketsAsignedTo] = true, obj), {})
);
```

Esto te debería devolver el siguiente array:

```
["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

Después se necesitan filtrar tus datos para agruparlos, para ello se puede generar un objeto compuesto por propiedades de tipo `TicketsClasificationType` y como valor de dichas propiedades, un objeto conformado por propiedades de tipo `TicketsAsignedTo` y valores `TicketsCount`:

```
const datasetsObject = consulta.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.TicketsClasificationType] = obj[item.TicketsClasificationType] || {};
    obj[item.TicketsClasificationType][item.TicketsAsignedTo] = item.TicketsCount;
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Esto devolverá un objeto como el siguiente:

```
{
    "Dataset 1": {A: 44, B: 55, C: 41, D: 37, E: 40},
    "Dataset 2": {A: 53, B: 32, C: 33, D: 52},
    "Dataset 3": {A: 12, B: 17, C: 11, D: 9},
    "Dataset 4": {A: 9,  B: 7,  C: 5,  D: 8}
}
```

Al tener los datos de la consulta ya agrupados, se podría generar el array de `datasets` que necesitas:

```
const datasets = Object.keys(datasetsObject).map(name => ({
    label: name,
    data: labels.map(l => datasetsObject[name][l] || 0)
}));
```

Aquí te dejo un snippet de ejemplo para que puedas ver el código funcionando:

```js
const consulta = [
    {TicketsCount: 44, TicketsAsignedTo: "A", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 1"},
    {TicketsCount: 55, TicketsAsignedTo: "B", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 1"},
    {TicketsCount: 41, TicketsAsignedTo: "C", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 1"},
    {TicketsCount: 37, TicketsAsignedTo: "D", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 1"},
    {TicketsCount: 53, TicketsAsignedTo: "A", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 2"},
    {TicketsCount: 32, TicketsAsignedTo: "B", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 2"},
    {TicketsCount: 33, TicketsAsignedTo: "C", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 2"},
    {TicketsCount: 52, TicketsAsignedTo: "D", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 2"},
    {TicketsCount: 12, TicketsAsignedTo: "A", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 3"},
    {TicketsCount: 17, TicketsAsignedTo: "B", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 3"},
    {TicketsCount: 11, TicketsAsignedTo: "C", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 3"},
    {TicketsCount: 9,  TicketsAsignedTo: "D", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 3"},
    {TicketsCount: 9,  TicketsAsignedTo: "A", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 4"},
    {TicketsCount: 7,  TicketsAsignedTo: "B", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 4"},
    {TicketsCount: 5,  TicketsAsignedTo: "C", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 4"},
    {TicketsCount: 8,  TicketsAsignedTo: "D", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 4"},
    {TicketsCount: 40, TicketsAsignedTo: "E", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 1"}
];

const labels = Object.keys(
    consulta.reduce((obj, label) => (obj[label.TicketsAsignedTo] = true, obj), {})
);

const colors = {
    "Dataset 1": "#22aa99",
    "Dataset 2": "#994499",
    "Dataset 3": "#316395",
    "Dataset 4": "#b82e2e"
};

const datasetsObject = consulta.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.TicketsClasificationType] = obj[item.TicketsClasificationType] || {};
    obj[item.TicketsClasificationType][item.TicketsAsignedTo] = item.TicketsCount;
    return obj;
}, {});

const datasets = Object.keys(datasetsObject).map(name => ({
    label: name,
    backgroundColor: colors[name],
    data: labels.map(l => datasetsObject[name][l] || 0)
}));

const context = document.getElementById("barChart").getContext("2d");
const myBarChart = new Chart(context, {
    type: "horizontalBar",
    data: { labels, datasets },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{ stacked: true }],
            yAxes: [{ stacked: true }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: aun no se sabe si la respuesta resuelve el problema, pero se ve que hubo mucha investigación.

Answer (score 0):

[En este fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/og95xevw/) hay un ejemplo adaptado de esta [pregunta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37499623/chart-js-stacked-and-grouped-bar-chart#answer-37616862), que te puede servir de base.

Si te fijas en `datasets`, cada elemento del mismo grupo repite `data`. La diferencia es que cambia el `stack`, que sería el subgrupo. Si pusieras los datos originales se podría dar mas detalle en cómo preparar los `datasets`.

```
datasets: [
    {
        label: "Apples",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(99,255,132,0.2)",
        data: [20, 10, 30],
        stack: 1
    },
    {
        label: "Apples",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(99,255,132,0.2)",
        data: [20, 10, 30],
        stack: 2
    },
    {
        label: "Apples",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(99,255,132,0.2)",
        data: [20, 10, 30],
        stack: 3
    }
]
```

Comment: Que mas datos te podría dar, el ejemplo que me das ya lo había consultado

Comment: la respuesta cruda de `data`

Comment: @SebastianSalazar el tema aquí es transformar tu `data` en una estructura compatible con el staked de Chart.js, entiendo que es solo esto.

Comment: Exactamente es como poder estructurar de la manera adecuada, si te fijas en la imagen de mi error en la parte inferior se repite el estado a parte de estado *ASIGNADO* tengo otros mas

Comment: Revisa la actualización que acabo de hacer con tu ejemplo no consigo resultado aun

Comment: @SebastianSalazar Es difícil saber exactamente qué falla, porque hay que hacer ingeniería reversa para tratar de averiguar cómo son realmente los datos, pero en principio no defines stack que es lo que en definitiva hace la magia.

Comment: Te está poniendo siempre el mismo stack.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99312/discussion-between-sebastian-salazar-and-emeeus).

Comment: gracias por la edición @ElChiniNet