# ¿Cómo ordenar de mayor a menor valor gráfica stacked bar usando Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Tengo un gráfico de barras apiladas (Stacked bar) que construí usando la librería [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) de `JavaScript`, y me gustaría que fueran ordenados de la siguiente manera: los elementos con mayor valor en la parte superior de la barra, los de menor valor en la parte inferior, es decir, en orden descendente.

Supongo que se puede lograr usando algunos de los complementos de `Chart.js`, pero aun no logro resolverlo.

La siguiente es la gráfica que estoy generando y se genera de manera desordenada:

El siguiente es el fragmento de código con el cual estoy construyendo la gráfica:

```
myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',           
    data: { labels, datasets },
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        showAllTooltips: true,
        scales: {
            xAxes: [
                {
                    stacked: true,
                    display: true,
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                    }
                }
            ],
            yAxes: [
                {
                    stacked: true,
                    display: true,    
                    reverse: false,
                    ticks: { }
                }
            ]
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
            padding: 5,
            labels: {
                pointStyle: 'circle',
                usePointStyle: true
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                color: "#333333",
                font: {
                    weight: 'bold',
                    size: 16,                          
                }
            }
        },
    },
});
```

**Version:** `Chart.js` v2.8.0

**Actualización:**

Agrego objetos `datasets` y `datasetsObject`

```
const datasetsObject = data.DashboardTicketList.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.TicketsClasificationType] = obj[item.TicketsClasificationType] || {};
    obj[item.TicketsClasificationType][item.TicketsAsignedTo] = item.TicketsCount;
    return obj;
}, {});

const datasets = Object.keys(datasetsObject).map((name) => ({
    label: name,
    backgroundColor: colors[name],
    data: labels.map((l) => datasetsObject[name][l])
}));
```

**Actualizacion 2:**

Los valores de los `datasets`

```
const colors = {
    "ABIERTO": "#F76363",
    "ASIGNADO": "#F7A65C",
    "EN PROCESO": "#F2CB5F",
    "EN ESPERA USUARIO": "#B283ED",
    "TERMINADO": "#4285f4",
    "CERRADO": "#6CE5CE",                
};
```

**Actualización 3:**

Al ejecutar el algoritmo de ordenamiento `sort` como me lo indicaron en una de las respuestas, ya no me representa ninguna dato en la gráfica

```
const datasets = Object.keys(datasetsObject).map((name) => ({
    label: name,
    backgroundColor: colors[name],
    data: labels.map((l) => datasetsObject[name][l]).sort
}));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: agrega el objeto que tienes en como `datasets`

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob revisa mi actualización agregue el objeto que pediste, saludos

Comment: El de datasetsObject también porfa

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza agregue ambos objetos, revisalo y me cuentas

Comment: El orden en el que pases los valores afecta en la gráfica directamente. Si es así te puedo ayudar rápidamente

Comment: @AndrusDiaz A que te refieres con afectar la gráfica, puede cambiar algún valor ?

Comment: Si al pasar valores de la siguiente manera: [1,2,3] se pintaran en ese orden. Por ende te puedo ayudar para crear una funcion que lo ordene

Comment: @AndrusDiaz Me parece bien, probare con la función que me pases que tal se ve, quedo atento

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veo que estás usando [la lógica que te di hace un tiempo atrás](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/296578) para generar los `datasets` y los `labels`. Bueno, tomando el mismo *snippet* que te di en su momento, voy a variarlo para ordenar los `labels` de mayor a menor tomando en cuenta la suma de sus valores. Para hacerlo, una de las soluciones es que en vez de generarlos de la manera anterior, podría generarse un objeto con los totales por `label`, crear un `array` con dicho objeto, organizar ese `array` de mayor a menor y después extraer los `labels` de ese `array` y así estos estarán ordenados de mayor a menor teniendo en cuenta la suma de todos sus valores. Te lo explico paso a paso:

Teniendo en cuenta el siguiente `array` con la consulta:

```
const consulta = [
    {TicketsCount: 1, TicketsAsignedTo: "A", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 1"},
    {TicketsCount: 1, TicketsAsignedTo: "B", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 1"},
    {TicketsCount: 3, TicketsAsignedTo: "C", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 2"},
    {TicketsCount: 1, TicketsAsignedTo: "D", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 1"},
    {TicketsCount: 2, TicketsAsignedTo: "A", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 2"},
    {TicketsCount: 1, TicketsAsignedTo: "B", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 2"},
    {TicketsCount: 2, TicketsAsignedTo: "D", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 2"},
    {TicketsCount: 1, TicketsAsignedTo: "A", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 3"},
    {TicketsCount: 2, TicketsAsignedTo: "D", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 4"},
    {TicketsCount: 6, TicketsAsignedTo: "E", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 5"}
];
```

1 - Crear un objeto de totales por `label`:

```
const totales = consulta.reduce((obj, row) => {
    obj[row.TicketsAsignedTo] = obj[row.TicketsAsignedTo] || 0;
    obj[row.TicketsAsignedTo] += row.TicketsCount;
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Lo anterior retornará un objeto como el siguiente:

```
{A: 4, B: 2, C: 3, D: 5, E: 6}
```

2 - Crear un array de `labels` y totales:

```
const labelsArray = Object.keys(totales).map(prop => ({
    label: prop,
    value: totales[prop]
}));
```

Lo que devolverá un `array` como el siguiente:

```
[
    {label: "A", value: 4},
    {label: "B", value: 2},
    {label: "C", value: 3},
    {label: "D", value: 5},
    {label: "E", value: 6}  
]
```

3 - Ordenar el `array` de mayor a menor tomando en cuenta la propiedad `value`:

```
labelsArray.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);
```

Lo que retornará el `array` ordenado de la siguiente manera:

```
[
    {label: "E", value: 6},
    {label: "D", value: 5},
    {label: "A", value: 4},
    {label: "C", value: 3},
    {label: "B", value: 2}
]
```

4 - Extraer los `labels` del `array` ordenado:

```
const labels = labelsArray.map(l => l.label);
```

Lo que devolverá:

```
["E", "D", "A", "C", "B"]
```

5 - Utilizar este `array` de `labels` para generar el gráfico:

```js
const consulta = [
    {TicketsCount: 1, TicketsAsignedTo: "A", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 1"},
    {TicketsCount: 1, TicketsAsignedTo: "B", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 1"},
    {TicketsCount: 3, TicketsAsignedTo: "C", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 2"},
    {TicketsCount: 1, TicketsAsignedTo: "D", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 1"},
    {TicketsCount: 2, TicketsAsignedTo: "A", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 2"},
    {TicketsCount: 1, TicketsAsignedTo: "B", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 2"},
    {TicketsCount: 2, TicketsAsignedTo: "D", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 2"},
    {TicketsCount: 1, TicketsAsignedTo: "A", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 3"},
    {TicketsCount: 2, TicketsAsignedTo: "D", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 4"},
    {TicketsCount: 6, TicketsAsignedTo: "E", TicketsClasificationType: "Dataset 5"}
];

const colors = {
    "Dataset 1": "#f7a65c",
    "Dataset 2": "#6ce5ce",
    "Dataset 3": "#f2cb5f",
    "Dataset 4": "#b283ed",
    "Dataset 5": "#f76363"
};

const datasetsObject = consulta.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.TicketsClasificationType] = obj[item.TicketsClasificationType] || {};
    obj[item.TicketsClasificationType][item.TicketsAsignedTo] = item.TicketsCount;
    return obj;
}, {});

// Generar un objeto con los totales
const totales = consulta.reduce((obj, row) => {
  obj[row.TicketsAsignedTo] = obj[row.TicketsAsignedTo] || 0;
  obj[row.TicketsAsignedTo] += row.TicketsCount;
  return obj;
}, {});

// Crear un array de labels y totales
const labelsArray = Object.keys(totales).map(prop => ({
  label: prop,
  value: totales[prop]
}));

// Organizar los labels teniendo en cuenta su total
labelsArray.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);

// Extraer los labels
const labels = labelsArray.map(l => l.label);

const datasets = Object.keys(datasetsObject).map(name => ({
    label: name,
    backgroundColor: colors[name],
    data: labels.map(l => datasetsObject[name][l] || 0)
}));

const context = document.getElementById("barChart").getContext("2d");
const myBarChart = new Chart(context, {
    type: "horizontalBar",
    data: { labels, datasets },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{ stacked: true }],
            yAxes: [{ stacked: true }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Algoritmo sort**
El algoritmo sort: que se encuentra implementado en los array de java script te permite organizar valores de manera automática.

**Ejemplo:**
En  este caso nuestros variables son:

```
let GroupValores = [[2,5,3],[2,1],[10,3,6,2]];
```

- Organizar gráficos por `GroupValores` de menor a mayor cantidad de datos:

```
GroupValores = GroupValores.sort((a,b) => a.length> b.length);
```

R: `[[2,1],[2,5,3],[10,3,6,2]]`

- Organizar gráficos de menor a mayor por cada valor de `GroupValores`:

```
GroupValores = GroupValores.map(val => val.sort((a,b) => a > b) );
```

R:  `[[2,3,5],[1,2],[2,3,6,10]]`

> Ahora solo te queda combinarlos o invertirlos para lo que deses

Comment: Quede en las mismas, pensé que ibas a dejarme el ejemplo con el código que publique en mi pregunta

Comment: @SebastianSalazar . En que parte te quedaste? Es simple cada array de ```GroupValores``` es un data y para que este este mas completo lo puedes convertir en un objeto con los valores de label y background. Es muy simple

Comment: En el inicio, se me olvida agregar que no tengo conocimientos muy solidos en javascript por eso solicito de su ayuda, si puedes dejarme el ejemplo con el codigo que tengo en mi pregunta

Comment: @SebastianSalazar ok para mayor comodidad en organizar los valor por favor en su demostración coloca los datos de datasets para darte un mejor ejemplo

Comment: Revisa la pregunta nuevamente acabo de colocar los valores de los datasets

Comment: Una observación: que un `array` tenga una longitud mayor que otro no significa que la suma de sus valores sea mayor y por otro lado, si organizas el `array` de valores, debes hacer lo mismo con el `array` de `labels`, de lo contrario desorganizarías el gráfico y a cada `label` le corresponderían valores erróneos.

Answer (score 0):

Donde armas los dataset debes ordenar los valores de cada uno con la función Sort() de los Arrays de Javascript

```
const datasets = Object.keys(datasetsObject).map((name) => ({
                label: name,
                backgroundColor: colors[name],
                data: labels.map((l) => datasetsObject[name][l]).Sort()
            }));
```

Con eso el valor del array `data` debería quedar ordenado de menor a mayor

Comment: Al colocar la funcion Sort() me genera el siguiente error `Uncaught TypeError: datasetsObject[name][l].Sort is not a function`

Comment: @SebastianSalazar hola de nuevo.. no coloques el sort en ```datasetsObject[name][l]``` FacePalm es en ```datasetsObject[name][l])``` despues del sierre del paréntesis :).

Comment: ```sort``` tiene que esta en minúscula

Comment: @AndrusDiaz revisa mi ultima actualización, agregando la función `sort` ya no me muestra ningún dato la gráfica

Comment: Esto no sería una buena idea, al ordenar los datos sin tener en cuenta el orden de los `labels` se desordenará el gráfico y cada valor no quedará en el lugar que le corresponde. También es bueno recordar que `sort` por defecto ordena tomando en cuenta el valor unicode, por lo que `[200,10,1,2,3].sort()` devolverá `[1, 10, 2, 200, 3]`.